# Interface entites and custom factories in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I use a framework that generates implementation classes for data interfaces like this one:

```
interface Person {
 String getName();
   void setName(String v);
    int getAge();
   void setAge(int v);
}
```

Instances are obtained via a factory API:

```
Persion p = MyFramework.create(Person.class);
```

I am willing to integrate this framework into my application's JPA component. Is there a way to configure Hibernate (can switch to EclipseLink too) to accept annotated interfaces as entities and to use custom factories for creating instances of them?

thank you

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: It's impossible for JPA to automatically recognize mapping for interfaces and treat them as entities. That being said, I'm not sure what your exact use case is, but perhaps the following link will be helpful: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic